# 3 level array in php to organize data

Tags: php, arrays

I want create a three-level array in php, with example data for developing purposes, I have this:

```
$data = array(
array(1 => array("A ROW GREENS", array(
    "A1" => array("http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg"),
    "A2" => array("http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg"),
    "A3" => array("http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg")
))),
array(2 => array("A ROW BLUE",array(
    "A1" => array("http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg"),
    "A2" => array("http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg"),
    "A3" => array("http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg")
))),

);
```

How you can see, this is the structure:

```
Element:[ID -> Title][IDSubitem1->URL, IDSubitem2->URL2...]
Element:[ID -> Title][IDSubitem1->URL, IDSubitem2->URL2...]
Element:[ID -> Title][IDSubitem1->URL, IDSubitem2->URL2...]
```

I need to print a `<ul>` with the Titles (using id for identifier them) and print other `<ul>` tags for show or hide the subitems or the selected parent.

```
<ul id="parent">
    <li id="1">A ROW GREENS</li>
    <li id="2">A ROW BLUE</li>
</ul>

<ul id="child1">
    <li id="child1-A1">http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg</li>
    <li id="child1-A2">http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg</li>
    <li id="child1-A3">http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg</li>
</ul>

<ul id="child2">
    <li id="child2-A1">http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg</li>
    <li id="child2-A2">http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg</li>
    <li id="child2-A3">http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: can you show what expected outcome you want? and what you have tried to achieve that?

Comment: Also your first input is seems wrong  `array(1 => "A ROW GREENS") =>
    array(`

Comment: I updated the desired result and change a little the data (before was wrong)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve your expected outcome like below:-

```
<?php
$data = array(
array(1 => array("A ROW GREENS", array(
    "A1" => array("http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg"),
    "A2" => array("http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg"),
    "A3" => array("http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg")
))),
array(2 => array("A ROW BLUE",array(
    "A1" => array("http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg"),
    "A2" => array("http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg"),
    "A3" => array("http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg")
))));

$parent_data = '';
$child_data = '';
foreach($data as $dat){
    foreach($dat as $key=>$da){
        $parent_data .="<li id ='".$key."'>".$da[0]."</li>";
        $child_data .="<ul id='child".$key."'>";
        foreach ($da[1] as $k=>$v){
             $child_data .="<li id='child".$key."-".$k."'>".$v[0]."</li>";
        }
        $child_data .="</ul>";
    }

}
?>
<ul id="parent"><?php echo $parent_data;?></ul><?php echo  $child_data;?>
```

Output:- https://eval.in/656522

Note:- The code will only work for the given array structure (element can be more, no problem), But if array structure is changed then code will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to use 3 foreach()

```
foreach($data as $level1)
{
  foreach(level1 as $level2)
  {
    foreach(level2 as $level3)
    {
```